# How does one create a data set in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, matplotlib, montecarlo

So, I am trying to create a data set of pi measurements by repeating a simulation using the same number of different random numbers each time and plot this data set as a histogram.

The first thing I did was to estimate pi using a Monte-Carlo method. I used N = 1000 random numbers (see code below). Then I created an empty list where the pi values will be stored later. After that, I created another for loop with range 100 and nested
 the for loop I created to estimate pi (with range 1000) under the new for loop (see code below). I don't know if that is a correct way of creating the data set. Please correct me.

```
[...importing modules (random, numpy and matplotlib)...] 

N= 1000 #total number of points
M = 100 #number of pi values

            

red_points_x = []
red_points_y = []
blue_points_x = []
blue_points_y = []

##Pi estimation
for i in range(N):
   x = np.random.rand()*2 -1
   y = np.random.rand()*2 -1
   if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
      red_points_x.append(x)
      red_points_y.append(y)

   else:
     blue_points_x.append(x)
     blue_points_y.append(y)

pi_mc = (4.0*(len(red_points_x)))/N
print(pi_mc)

          
#Creating a data set for pi

list_of_pis = []

 for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
       x = np.random.rand()*2 -1
       y = np.random.rand()*2 -1
       if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
           red_points_x.append(x)
           red_points_y.append(y)
       else:
           blue_points_x.append(x)
           blue_points_y.append(y)

    #pi = (4.0*(len(red_points_x)))/N
    list_of_pis.append(pi)

print(list_of_pis)
```

But I am getting the wrong values of pi (see below).

Output:

```
[313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06, 313.06,...]
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to calculate pi a bunch of times and histogram the distribution of the pi's calculated (which should be roughly symmetric and peak around pi).

I hope my code is not too long. I tried to minimise it as much as I can but the parts of the code I included are very important. Please help, your help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: you commented out the line where the value of pi is computed

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741407/how-to-plot-the-monte-carlo-pi-histogram/61741580#61741580) (*very* similar actually...).

Concerning your problem, did you notice that you append always the same value to your list? The problem is that you commented out the line:

```py
#pi = (4.0*(len(red_points_x)))/N
```

Hence, `pi` is the same number throughout your code (probably set when you do your first execution).

Concerning the fact that this value is wrong, it is probably due to the fact that you don't empty your lists between your two executions. Hence, do add these lines before your two `for` loops:

```py
red_points_x = []
red_points_y = []
blue_points_x = []
blue_points_y = []
```

Your code looks correct otherwise.